# Detecting the number of connected monitors always returns 1 or more instead of 0

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I have a Windows application that needs to detect the correct number of connected monitors during runtime.

So far, all of the methods that I have been able to find on the internet and Stack Overflow have failed. They all return 1, whether or not a screen is actually connected. And when 2 screens are connected, some of them correctly return 2, however, none of them return 0 when no screens are connected. I need it to return a 0 when no screen is connected.

Even a method that detects whether or not a screen is connected would work.

Below is a list of the code of the 6 methods that I have tried.

```
int numberOfScreens = 0;

        numberOfScreens = Screen.AllScreens.Length; //1 DOESN'T WORK

        numberOfScreens = SystemInformation.MonitorCount; //2 DOESN'T WORK

        numberOfScreens = GetSystemMetrics(80); //3 DOESN'T WORK

        /*4 DOESN'T WORK 
         * //This code was outside of the function
         * [DllImport("user32")]
         * private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lpRect, MonitorEnumProc callback, int dwData);
         * private delegate bool MonitorEnumProc(IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref Rect pRect, int dwData);
         * [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
         * private struct Rect {
         *     public int left;
         *     public int top;
         *     public int right;
         *     public int bottom;
         * }
         */
        int monCount = 0;
        Rect r = new Rect();
        MonitorEnumProc callback = (IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref Rect prect, int d) => ++monCount > 0;
        if (EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0)) {
            Console.WriteLine("You have {0} monitors", monCount);
            numberOfScreens = monCount;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured while enumerating monitors");
        }

        //5 DOESN'T WORK 
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where service =\"monitor\"");
        numberOfScreens = searcher.Get().Count;

        //6 DOESN'T WORK
        var active = true;
        var query = "select * from WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams";
        using (var wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\wmi", query)) {
            var results = wmiSearcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject wmiObj in results) {
                // get the "Active" property and cast to a boolean, which should 
                // tell us if the display is active. I've interpreted this to mean "on"
                active = (Boolean)wmiObj["Active"];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(active);
```

If there are any other reliable methods of detecting the correct number of displays, I would appreciate the help.

Thank you!

---

On a side note, the EDID_OVERRIDE in the registry for Default_Monitor is set so that no matter what happens, the EDID doesn't change. This isn't something I can change. But it is possible that this is the reason Windows says there is a monitor when there actually isn't. This would mean that it doesn't count monitors by how many are actually connected, but by the number of displays that it thinks it's rendering to.

Given this suspicion, is there a method by which I can detect the number of monitors actually connected? Like, how many HDMI/DVI/VGA cables are plugged in, as opposed to how many screens Windows thinks it's rendering to?

Comment: Try playing around with the winapi such as this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesw

Comment: Great question BTW.  I've exhausted my testing and googling.  I would just start grabbing all the winapi stuff about displays and adapters and start writing something to just loop and print it out.

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi - One of the methods did use winapi, the EnumDisplayMonitors function specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors - However, messing around a bit more in the api might give me some useful results, but I'm not hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

After a great deal of tinkering and head scratching, I managed to create a function that reliably returns the correct number of connected screens, even if that number changes while the program is running, and even if the number of connected screens is 0.

This means it can also be used to detect whether or not a screen / display / monitor is connected to the computer at all.

## Function:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

/// <summary>
/// Returns the number of monitors currently connected to the computer.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>(int) number of monitors</returns>
public int getNumberOfConnectedMonitors() {
    int numberOfMonitors = 1;

    //Detect number of monitors. However, this does NOT work when no monitors are connected. It instead gives a 1.
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where service =\"monitor\"");
    numberOfMonitors = searcher.Get().Count;

    //Get's the monitor's instance name. "Default_Monitor" is the "monitor" Windows defaults to when nothing is connected
    string activeScreen = "";
    using (var wmiSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\root\\wmi", "select * from WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams")) {
        var results = wmiSearcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject wmiObj in results) {
            // tell us if the display is active
            var active = (Boolean)wmiObj["Active"];
            //Get the instance name of the active monitor
            if (active) {
                activeScreen = (string)wmiObj["InstanceName"];
            }
        }
    }

    //If Windows says only one monitor is connected and that monitor is Default_Monitor, then that means that there are no monitors detected by Windows
    if(numberOfMonitors == 1 && activeScreen.Contains("Default_Monitor")) {
        numberOfMonitors = 0;
    }

    return numberOfMonitors;
}
```

---

## Details and Explanation (if you want that)

The above function is a Frankenstein mixture of method 5 and method 6 (seen in the question).

First it gets the number of monitors from method 5, which reliably gave the correct number when the number of connected monitors was greater than 0 (at least with the monitors that I tested). However, it returns 1 when there are actually 0 monitors connected.

Second it gets the name of one of the active monitors through a modified version of method 6. Method 6 uses the [WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmicoreprov/wmimonitorbasicdisplayparams) to get info about the connected monitors. First it checks if the monitor is active. If it is, then it will get the monitor's instance name. The instance name comes in a form that looks like `DISPLAY\(monitorNameHere)\(seeminglyRandomValuesHere)`.

If there is only one monitor connected, and that monitor's instance name contains "Default_Monitor", then that means no valid monitors are currently connected, and the function returns a 0.

"Default_Monitor" is the name that Windows gives to the "monitor" that it displays to when no monitors are detected. (at least, no monitors that give a valid [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data))

---

Now, it may just be that the reason the original functions weren't working for me was because I have Default_Monitor set to have an EDID of its own. However, I think that this function will still be reliable regardless.

This function is also great for detecting whether or not a screen/display/monitor is connected (because if not, it returns 0), which is something that I was also unable to find anywhere else on the internet, leading me to believe that those functions wouldn't return 0 even if I didn't have an EDID set up for Default_Monitor.

Either way, this function works reliably in my testing.